# How to correctly handle adding new item to dictionary?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, addition

I have an ASP.NET application where I use static class as cache. Inside that static class is internal dictionary, which holds cached objects. Of course, in static class are methods like Add/Remove/Clear... It looks as follows:

```
public static class CacheManager
{
    private static Dictionary<string, object> cacheItems = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    private static ReaderWriterLockSlim locker = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public static Dictionary<string, object> CacheItems
    {
        get
        {
            return cacheItems;
        }
    }

    public static void AddCacheItem(string key, object data)
    {
        locker.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            cacheItems.Add(key, data);
        }
        finally
        {
            locker.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

The items was added to the cache (dictionary) when ASP.NET application runs. I just want to ask should I check for example in Add method if key is already added in this way:

```
    public static void AddCacheItem(string key, object data)
    {
        locker.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            if (!cacheItems.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                cacheItems.Add(key, data);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            locker.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
```

Or leave it as is in first code snippet?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm more concerned with how code that reads from the `CacheItems` property is going to enter a read lock...

Comment: You mean I also should put there some synchronization stuff?

Comment: What about **ConcurrentDictionary**.  Or are you not using .Net 4.0?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx

Comment: Does it matter to the caller whether the item was added or not?

Comment: since you are exposing the dictionary all bets are off on the syncronization (even if all reads were syncronized) you could still add items without sync. A good example of where Law of Demeter would avoid the problems you might face

Comment: yes, if concurrency is an issue as your example suggests, you should handle CRUD http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete and leave the dictionary in its place, not exposing it direcly.

Comment: @tesicg Adding a read lock inside of the `CacheItems` property won't help -- you'll lock, unlock, and return a reference to the dictionary.  Consuming code will be able to read from the dictionary while not holding a read lock.  Consider not exposing the dictionary at all and adding a method to get a cache item by key; you can do the appropriate locking in that method.

Comment: cdhowie, you wrote this: "Consider not exposing the dictionary at all and adding a method to get a cache item by key; you can do the appropriate locking in that method." Could you, please, write code snippet?

Comment: @cdhowie, How can I go through all dictionary items on client side if I don't expose the dictionary?

Comment: @tesicg `public object GetCacheItem(string key) { locker.EnterReadLock(); try { object value; cacheItems.TryGetValue(key, out value); return value; } finally { locker.ExitReadLock(); } }` This assumes that `null` is an appropriate return value when the cached item cannot be found.  (If you need to actually cache `null` as a value then you will need to use an `out object` parameter and return `bool` instead.)

Comment: Also, since you are using `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, you might be interested in [this class that I contributed to Cadenza](http://gitorious.org/cadenza/cadenza/blobs/master/src/Cadenza.Core/Cadenza.Threading/ReaderWriterLockSlimCoda.cs).  It allows you to simplify locking code to, for example, `using (locker.Write()) { cacheItems[key] = data; }`.  It's MIT-licensed, so you are free to embed it in proprietary code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement one more method TryAdd

```
public static bool TryAddCacheItem(string key, object data)
{
    locker.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
        if (cacheItems.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return false;
        }
        cacheItems.Add(key, data);
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        locker.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

Also I would suggest to use [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267291.aspx). [Here](http://code.google.com/p/codesmith/source/browse/trunk/Templates/Frameworks/PLINQO/Source/CodeSmith.Data/Collections/ConcurrentDictionary.cs?r=1991) is the code of the ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: I understand it, but which one should be used on client and why my second code snippet is not enough?

Comment: It all depends on what is the responsibility of the AddCacheItem method. In k0stya code it notifies the calling class if it failed. The question is if your logic needs to know, if adding a cache item failed.

Comment: Your suggestion about using ConcurrentDictionary is ok, but we use .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: Eiver, I've understood what k0stya wrote. We actually don't need to know if AddCacheItem method failed. We only should make sure the duplicate key is not added. My second code snippet should be enough in that case?

Comment: Then the second is enough. Anyway take a look at http://code.google.com/p/codesmith/source/browse/trunk/Templates/Frameworks/PLINQO/Source/CodeSmith.Data/Collections/ConcurrentDictionary.cs?r=1991

Answer (score 0):

Just execute twice:

`cacheItems.Add(key, data);`

...and you will know the answer. Basically the exception will be thrown and caught by the try/finally block. I would personally use the if statement rather than putting all the logic responsibility on the try block, but its a question of preference...

Comment: Yes. I did it and there's an exception if I don't use my second code snippet. That's why I'm asking this.

Comment: Well, typically I use exceptions for the unexpected stuff. If you use the try block, then in general you will not have any idea about what has happened. The dictionary.add() is easy, because it just throws ArgumentNullException or ArgumentException. Other methods may throw the same exception type for different reasons (or even just exception). I would say - use the if statement, because you enter the "else" statement then you know excactly what happened. I would use a try catch block in cases like socket.connect(), because it is impossible to do if(socket.CanConnect())